# RTL only works with multiple lines

Tags: android, textview, hebrew

I've got an Android app, which can read RSS feeds. I've got RTL supported in my manifest. When I display an RSS feed which is in Hebrew / Arab with RTL something remarkable happens.

[image]
The image shows how the text in the textview (in the list) correctly aligns long text, that takes up 2+ lines, right. However, 1 line text is not correctly aligned. All text is parsed and set to the textview the same way.

This is my textview style:

```
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:lineSpacingExtra">1dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">2dp</item>
    <item name="android:maxLines">2</item>
    <item name="android:ellipsize">end</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/dark_gray</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-light</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium</item>
```

What causes this difference? And how can I make sure all (hebrew/arab) text is aligned right.

Comment: Try paddingStart instead of paddingLeft. Only that among the above attributes in the defined style seems to affect in RTL mode.

Comment: @gauravjain Tried, but does not seem to affect the direction

Comment: Can you include your layout?

Comment: @ianhanniballake Sure, please check: http://pastebin.com/Fd9YP4yy

Comment: @mdlc in the relative layout, change marginLeft to marginStart and marginRight to marginEnd. Also, in the textview, change layout_toRightOf attribute to "layout_toEndOf". This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use a `layout_width` of `wrap_content`, the width of your view adjusts based on how much content exists. In the case of short strings, that means that the right edge of your view is right at the edge of the text, rather than tied to the right edge of your `FrameLayout`. This causes even the right aligned text to appear left aligned.

Instead, you should fix both edges of the `TextView` - you already handle the left edge via `android:layout_toRightOf` - add `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` as well so that the rightmost edge of the view will always correspond with the rightmost edge of the FrameLayout.

Comment: You're completely right. Should have used 'show layout bounds', it would have saved me a few hours of my time.

Answer (score 2):

Please check the official Android developer's blog link : http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2013/03/native-rtl-support-in-android-42.html. This should help you in dealing with RTL. Also for textview, if you need the text to start from a particular direction (left or right for different modes), you can use textAlignment property and set it to viewStart. Hope this helps.

Comment: I find your answer to be very general. I'm aware of the ways to align texts, and apply correct RTL paddings. I'm more interested in the specific situation where this specific alignment problem occurs.